# Declare Decimals in MVC 4 Controller Parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is the error that I am getting right now:

```
The argument types 'Edm.String' and 'Edm.Decimal' are incompatible for this operation. Near equals expression, line 1, column 156.
```

I know that this error is a compatibility issue but after going through the table and seeing that the parameters match up and I think are declared properly I would need to know the line of code that this references.  The only ones that I would question are the data that are declared as money in the table but I declare them as decimal.  This is the code that bombs out

```
        public ActionResult Details(int PVID = 0, int PMID = 0, decimal AID = 0.00M, decimal TID =0.00M, string TyID = null, string NID = null, decimal AmID = 0.00M, decimal PID = 0.00M, string TNID = null, string INID = null, DateTime? DEID = null, decimal IBID = 0.00M, decimal PBID = 0.00M, DateTime? LMDID = null)
    {
        tblDenialReport tbldenialreport = db.tblDenialReport.Find(PVID, PMID, AID, TID, TyID, NID, AmID, PID, TNID, INID, DEID, IBID, PBID, LMDID);
        if (tbldenialreport == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();

        }
        return View(tbldenialreport);
    }
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Are all those key values for model?

Comment: Yes it is actually a stored procedure that was several tables joined.  I then took the result set and created a table to use

Comment: Would it matter if the decimal values are declared as "money" in sql server?

Comment: Yes actually you should use the same datatype for the value at any place. I mean if you are storing money in that field, then put it as money datatype

Comment: Ok forgive my stupidity but is there a money datatype in c#.  I always thought it was decimal?

Comment: You will get a lot of errors of rounding for decimals, so to avoid those, you can use Money. Still double is more popular

Comment: So in the parameter declaration it would be like this SqlDbType.Money AID = 0.00M ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass either the primary key or composite key as a parameter to [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) .You are doing it wrong here:

```
tblDenialReport tbldenialreport = db.tblDenialReport.Find(PVID, PMID, AID, TID, TyID, NID, AmID, PID, TNID, INID, DEID, IBID, PBID, LMDID);
```

- [`DbSet<TEntity>.Find Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) uses the primary key value to attempt to find an entity tracked by the context.
- If the entity is not in the context then a query will be executed and evaluated against the data in the data source, and null is returned if the entity is not found in the context or in the data source.
- **Note that** the Find also returns entities that have been added to the context but have not yet been saved to the database.

If you want to search for the tblDenialReport with above parameters, then you can do it as below:

```
public ActionResult Details(int PVID = 0, int PMID = 0, decimal AID = 0.00M, decimal TID =0.00M, string TyID = null, string NID = null, decimal AmID = 0.00M, decimal PID = 0.00M, string TNID = null, string INID = null, DateTime? DEID = null, decimal IBID = 0.00M, decimal PBID = 0.00M, DateTime? LMDID = null)
    {
        tblDenialReport tbldenialreport = db.tblDenialReport.SingleOrDefault(r=>

             r.PVID == PVID &&  r.PMID == PMID && r.AID == AID &&
             r.TID ==TID && r.TyID == TyID && r.NID == NID && r.AmID == AmID && 
             r.PID == PID && r.TNID == TNID && r.INID == INID && r.DEID == DEID &&
             r.IBID == IBID && r.PBID == PBID && r.LMDID == LMDID);

        if (tbldenialreport == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();

        }
        return View(tbldenialreport);
    }
```

But, I will strongly recommend you passing only the unique key of the tblDenialReport in the function name and then just doing it as below:

```
public ActionResult Details(int tblDenailReportId)
    {
        tblDenialReport tbldenialreport = db.tblDenialReport.Find(tblDenailReportId);

        if (tbldenialreport == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();

        }
        return View(tbldenialreport);
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide a snippet using this method please.  The example on the MS site is too vague

Comment: @MaximusPrime You want to find the tblDenialReport with all those values right?

Comment: @MaximusPrime Are all these values in the same table?

Comment: Yes I executed the stored procedure and dumped the result set into a table.  The stored procedure joined 5 different tables however but I don't think that is relavant

Comment: Thank you I will take you advice and create an ID on the tblDenialReport\

Answer (score -1):

Based upon the error message I would guess the error is due to the fact that `db.tblDenialReport.Find(...)` expects an integer but you're passing strings and decimals as well.

Comment: Check it here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

Comment: Ok, I understand that the method can handle all kind of variables. But shouldn't they still be of the same kind? If the ID of the table is integer wouldn't there be an error if you send decimals and strings to the Find method? I guess I have some more reading to do here. Thanks for the link...

Comment: :You can also have composite key consisting of an `int` and `string`, at that time you can pass an int as well as string separated by comma.

Comment: You're speaking wisdom! Thanks for enlighten me :-)